# Date on entry stamp issue for extension of titre de séjour

Tags: france

I currently have a long stay visa in France.

I recently applied to extend my *titre de séjour*. I received a notification asking for the date on my entry stamp to be the day my visa started, on January 7th.

But, I entered the country before this date, on December 13th, because I have a US passport, which allows me to enter the area without a visa.

My date of entry stamp is Dec 13th and my visa is valid Jan 7th.
I am not sure how to explain that I was able to enter the country before my visa started.

I am worried they will deny me the extension because of this technicality.

I tried to call the prefecture but maybe someone here has a better contact for me? Has anyone been in this situation? I am not sure what I can do to be approved and explain why I entered the country beforehand.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88153/how-to-switch-from-tourist-visa-to-resident-visa-status-in-the-schengen-area Explain that you entered visa-free for tourism (or whatever reason it was that is allowed under visa-free entry rules)

Comment: "I received a notification asking for the date on my entry stamp to be the day my visa started, on January 7th." What does that mean exactly? You got a letter asking you to submit additional evidence? Also, what kind of *carte de séjour* are you applying for?